# Ldaptive design for JavaEE ANT web project

Tags: jakarta-ee, ldap

I'm having some issues trying to set up [Ldaptive](http://www.ldaptive.org/) API in a web project.

I need to know how connection pooling can be properly set up within the project, and how users can connect to the same pool.

In spring it seems easier to use due to setting it up in the initial context config, but how can this work for a standard java web project?

My methods are all written, and I've adapted all of the code (many lines), but can't seem to work it out.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can post ldaptive questions here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ldaptive